# Transfer Table TD in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

This is the way on how I populate data in my table.

```
<script>
function GenerateTable() {
    <? var data = getData(); ?> 

    var table = document.getElementById("TableContainer");

    <? for (var i = 12; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
      var getval;
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var row_did = row.insertCell(0);
      var row_area = row.insertCell(1);
      var row_cusname = row.insertCell(2);
      var row_pic = row.insertCell(3);
      var row_remarks = row.insertCell(4);
      var row_status = row.insertCell(5);
      var row_docudate = row.insertCell(6);
      var row_button = row.insertCell(7);

      row_did.innerHTML =      '<td  id="dataid" class="dataid">'+ <?= data[i][0] ?> + '</td>';
      row_area.innerHTML =     '<td  id="area" class="area">'+ <?= data[i][1] ?> +'<td>';
      row_cusname.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="cusname" class="cusname">' + <?= data[i][2] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_pic.innerHTML =      '<td  id ="cic" class="cic">' + <?= data[i][3] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_remarks.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="remarks" class="remarks">' + <?= data[i][4] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_status.innerHTML =   '<td  id ="status" class="status">' +<?= data[i][5] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_docudate.innerHTML = '<td  id ="docdate" class="docdate">'+ <?= data[i][6] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_button.innerHTML =   '<td><img id = "selectdata" class = "click-to-select" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0By6kUPbaVMWCbUI0LTJTR2g2N3M" alt="Submit" width="13px" height="13px" title = "Edit Selected Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></td>';

<? } ?>
}
</script>
```

and this is my table where i put the data based on code above.

```
<table  id = "TableContainer" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" width ="100%" align = "center" class="hoverTable">
   <tr>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">#</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">Area</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen" width = "200px"><font color="white">Customer Name</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">Person In Charge</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen" width = "250px"><font color="white">Remarks</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">Status</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">Doc. Date</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>

   </tr>
</table>
```

Please bear with me. this code is perfectly running and im running the code by `'<body onLoad = "GenerateTable()">` how ever as what you see on my code there is a code that looks like this.

```
<td><img id = "selectdata" class = "click-to-select" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0By6kUPbaVMWCbUI0LTJTR2g2N3M" alt="Submit" width="13px" height="13px" title = "Edit Selected Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></td>';
```

now it will create an image button for every row in my table and that code has a purpose and that is to transfer the data from td to textbox and other elements and here is my code for that.

```
<script>
$('.click-to-select').click(function() {
    var dataid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.dataid').text();
    var area = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.area').text();
    var cusname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.cusname').text();
    var cicoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.cic').text();
    var remarks = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.remarks').text();
    var statoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.status').text();
    var documentdate = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.docdate').text();

    $('#dataid').val(dataid)
    $('#areaoption').val(area)
    $('#cusname').val(cusname)
    $('#cicoption').val(cicoption)
    $('#remarks').val(remarks)
    $('#statoption').val(statoption)
    $('#documentdate').val(documentdate)
});
</script>
```

this is where the error starts when im clicking the image the row data is not transferring in my textbox whats the error?

Updated Code

```
<script>
function GenerateTable() {
    <? var data = getData(); ?> 

    var table = document.getElementById("TableContainer");

    <? for (var i = 12; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var row_did = row.insertCell(0);
      var row_area = row.insertCell(1);
      var row_cusname = row.insertCell(2);
      var row_pic = row.insertCell(3);
      var row_remarks = row.insertCell(4);
      var row_status = row.insertCell(5);
      var row_docudate = row.insertCell(6);
      var row_button = row.insertCell(7);

      row_did.innerHTML =      '<td  id="dataid" class="dataid">'+ <?= data[i][0] ?> + '</td>';
      row_area.innerHTML =     '<td  id="area" class="area">'+ <?= data[i][1] ?> +'<td>';
      row_cusname.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="cusname" class="cusname">' + <?= data[i][2] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_pic.innerHTML =      '<td  id ="cic" class="cic">' + <?= data[i][3] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_remarks.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="remarks" class="remarks">' + <?= data[i][4] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_status.innerHTML =   '<td  id ="status" class="status">' +<?= data[i][5] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_docudate.innerHTML = '<td  id ="docdate" class="docdate">'+ <?= data[i][6] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_button.innerHTML =   '<td><img id = "selectdata" class = "click-to-select" src= "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0By6kUPbaVMWCbUI0LTJTR2g2N3M" alt="Submit" width="13px" height="13px" title = "Edit Selected Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></td>';

<? } ?>

$('.click-to-select').click(function() {
    var dataid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.dataid').text();
    var area = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.area').text();
    var cusname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.cusname').text();
    var cicoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.cic').text();
    var remarks = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.remarks').text();
    var statoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.status').text();
    var documentdate = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.docdate').text();

    $('#dataid').val(dataid)
    $('#areaoption').val(area)
    $('#cusname').val(cusname)
    $('#cicoption').val(cicoption)
    $('#remarks').val(remarks)
    $('#statoption').val(statoption)
    $('#documentdate').val(documentdate)
});

}
</script>
```

TYSM

Comment: There's too much code here to simulate in mind. Can you create a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: that will be hard for me because it is created in google script. I mean all of the code that you see is inside google sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you put your second script `$('.click-to-select').click(function(){...})` inside of `GenerateTable()` and after the for loop? Then check if the click handler is running by putting `console.log('The dataid is:' + dataid)` in here.

```
$('.click-to-select').click(function(){...
  ...
  var documentdate = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.docdate').text();

  console.log('The dataid is:' + dataid)

  $('#dataid').val(dataid)
  ...
}
```

I can't tell for sure the order that your code executes because you have two separate script tags here, but it's possible your second script can't bind the click handler because the `.click-to-select`s haven't been created yet by `GenerateTable()`.

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3hcbcg0/2/) using nth-of-type selectors

Comment: i try what you did but nothing happens it gives me an empty value in textboxes. please see the updated code.

Comment: Check out the edit, logging there will tell you 1) if the click handler runs on click and 2) if there are other problems with grabbing the text from the table

Comment: Ok so the click works now and you need to grab the text. I'm not sure if your selectors are working, I'm not even sure you can have classes and ids on <td> elements so how about using nth-of-type selectors like this `var dataid= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text();` Just increase the number as you go down the list.

Comment: and we have a winner haha joke. TYSM for the big help

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the id from td because some of it matches with textbox element.

Then replace it with below line of code and do the same for each column.

```
var dataid =  $(this).parent().siblings('.dataid').text();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think , This function should be like below 
Don't use the php tags because these are javascript variables .

```
function GenerateTable() {
   var data = getData();  

   var table = document.getElementById("TableContainer");

  for (var i = 12; i < data.length; i++) { 
     var row = table.insertRow(-1);
     var row_did = row.insertCell(0);
     var row_area = row.insertCell(1);
     var row_cusname = row.insertCell(2);
     var row_pic = row.insertCell(3);
     var row_remarks = row.insertCell(4);
     var row_status = row.insertCell(5);
     var row_docudate = row.insertCell(6);
     var row_button = row.insertCell(7);

  row_did.innerHTML =      '<td  id="dataid" class="dataid">'+  data[i][0]  + '</td>';
  row_area.innerHTML =     '<td  id="area" class="area">'+  data[i][1] +'<td>';
  row_cusname.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="cusname" class="cusname">' +  data[i][2]   +'<td>';
  row_pic.innerHTML =      '<td  id ="cic" class="cic">' +  data[i][3]   +'<td>';
  row_remarks.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="remarks" class="remarks">' + data[i][4]  +'<td>';
  row_status.innerHTML =   '<td  id ="status" class="status">' + data[i][5]   +'<td>';
  row_docudate.innerHTML = '<td  id ="docdate" class="docdate">'+  data[i][6]   +'<td>';
  row_button.innerHTML =   '<td><img id = "selectdata" class = "click-to-select" src= "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0By6kUPbaVMWCbUI0LTJTR2g2N3M" alt="Submit" width="13px" height="13px" title = "Edit Selected Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></td>';

    } 

$('.click-to-select').click(function() {
   var dataid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.dataid').text();
   var area = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.area').text();
   var cusname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.cusname').text();
   var cicoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.cic').text();
   var remarks = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.remarks').text();
   var statoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.status').text();
   var documentdate = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.docdate').text();

    $('#dataid').val(dataid)
    $('#areaoption').val(area)
    $('#cusname').val(cusname)
    $('#cicoption').val(cicoption)
    $('#remarks').val(remarks)
    $('#statoption').val(statoption)
    $('#documentdate').val(documentdate)
});


}
```

Hopefully , it may help you .

Comment: it is not php, its google app script scriplet...check the tags before you answer

Comment: @Ritz thanks for aware me about tags. But as i checked the Google App Script also don't use these(<?= ?> , <? ?>) tags.

Comment: Just go thru this [Google App Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#standard_scriptlets)